# Replace Erlang shell with system command

Tags: erlang

Is it possible to replace the erl shell with a system command? Similar to how you would with a POSIX `exec` call?

I'm trying to set up an SSH server in Erlang that gives a separate CLI instead of the built in one. I'm aware of OpenSSH's sshd's options to do this; does Erlang have something similar?

For example, how would I get the following command to work as it does with `sshd(8)` in an Erlang environment?

```sh
# connect to Erlang SSH server and drop into IPython shell
ssh user@host ipython
```

I have the server working fine—I'm able to connect without problems—and I know that you can develop your own CLI with the ssh_cli option for `ssh:daemon`. It might have something to do with ports and drivers or the `user_drv:start` command, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how this all works.

Comment: I'd try calling `exec` from within a NIF: http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html

Comment: No, there is not `exec()` call in the standard library. In systems which should run forever, nobody considered it an issue.

Comment: @legoscia that does indeed work! Thank you. It looks like I'll need to do more to get it to work on the SSH client's end, since this seems to just replace the server's process, even when called from the client.